# Craft Commerce: After add to cart, redirect to specific line item

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm building a craftcommerce based site, where each item added to the cart must be individually customised through a wizard interface.

When the item first gets added to the cart, I'd like to immediately redirect to a page where we can customise the item further

Something like the redirect shown below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="commerce/item?item={id}">
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="purchasableId" value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}">
<input type="submit" value="{{ "Buy"|t }}" class="btn btn-default"/>
```

This is possible with user form submission for instance, where the newly created user id is accessible via the method described above.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple plugin to redirect using the [onAddToCart method](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_cart.onaddtocart)

```
  craft()->on('commerce_cart.onAddToCart', function($event){

      $lineItem = $event->params['lineItem'];

      craft()->request->redirect("/commerce/item/?item=" . $lineItem->id);

  });
```